# ClassNotFoundException while Running Java Application

Tags: java

I am getting a ClassNotFOundException while running a code.I am using Eclipse.
Although it has main method with proper arguments it is still not able to launch the code.
Package name and import is also correct.

```
public class TestNew {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> sumList=new ArrayList<String>();

        Cm cm=new Cm();
        sumList=cm.sumListCombo();
        for(int i=0;i<=sumList.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println(sumList.get(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Import of respective packages are done.

Comment: *it is still not able to launch the code* + *while running a code* = contradictory.

Comment: What class is not being found?

Comment: Where is `Cm` defined? What is on your classpath? You need to post the full code (including the imports) and the full details of the ClassNotFoundException as well as the arguments you are passing to java to start your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refreshing the Project, then clean it and build it. If there is no problems, your code will work. If there is a problem, it will be some kind of 'Organize Imports' issue. Ctrl+Shift+o and you are ready.

Comment: This is the last time when I will try to answer to a retarded question written by someone with exactly '1' reputation. These people never accepts answers, nor provide feedback and their questions are poorly written/formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `O` if you're on windows.

This organizes your imports(adds missing ones and removes unnecessary ones).

Then on the menu bar, `Project >> Clean...`

Then re-launch your app.